# Salesforce OpenCti Lightning

Tags: lightning, console, opencti

​I created a call center definition to prepare to view use in salesforce lightning see below, but I can not seem to see how to make the app visible. I click on AppManager, New Lightning App, Fill in the required fields, In "App Options" I choose console navigation, and attempt to add the call center app to the Utility Bar Items but I can't see it. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<callCenter>
  <section sortOrder="0" name="reqGeneralInfo" label="General Info">
    <item sortOrder="0" name="reqInternalName" label="Internal Name">SymbeeEMCLightningAdapter2</item>
    <item sortOrder="1" name="reqDisplayName" label="Display Name">Symbee Lightning EMC Call Center Adapter</item>
    <item sortOrder="2" name="reqDescription" label="Description">Symbee softphone integrated into Avaya EMC Platform</item>
    <item sortOrder="3" name="reqAdapterUrl" label="Symbee Adapter URL">https://xxxxxx/xxxxx/xxxx/xxxxx.aspx</item>
    <item sortOrder="4" name="reqSalesforceCompatibilityMode" label="Salesforce Compatibility Mode">Lightning</item>
    <item sortOrder="5" name="reqUseApi" label="Use CTI API">true</item>
    <item sortOrder="6" name="reqSoftphoneHeight" label="Softphone Height">650</item>
    <item sortOrder="7" name="reqSoftphoneWidth" label="Softphone Width">320</item>
  </section>

  <section sortOrder="1" name="DialingOptions" label="Dialing Options">
    <item sortOrder="0" name="reqOutsidePrefix" label="Outside Prefix">9</item>
    <item sortOrder="1" name="LongDistPrefix" label="Long Distance Prefix">1</item>
    <item sortOrder="2" name="InternationalPrefix" label="International Prefix">01</item>
  </section>
</callCenter>
```

Comment: My call center definition didn't display, so I re-entered it:

Comment: It seems like it's too long, but the main element that I added was     <item sortOrder="4" name="reqSalesforceCompatibilityMode" label="Salesforce Compatibility Mode">Lightning</item>